# Is there any way to make Google Docs document view default to compact controls?

Tags: google-drive, customization

Whenever I open a document in Google Docs for editing, I push <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to set the mode to Compact Controls. I find this view simply superior, to the standard view, so I would like to make it my default view. Is that possible? I would be happy to use a plugin in either Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Google Docs remember "Compact Controls" mode only for Spreadsheets.

There's a plugin for Chrome called [Compactor for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ofmjpiklbebgedofgciaieofbhhpkpon).

However, since Spreadsheets remember the last setting, the plugin will effectively toggle the mode each time you open a Spreadsheet doc, but will work correctly with other types.

So, at the moment, it seems there is no really good way to reliably and permanently switch to Compact Controls. Hopefully, either Google Docs, or plugin author fixes that soon.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Google Docs saves the view setting for Spreadsheet, Presentation and Document.

Comment: And as of September 2018, it didn't...